# DevExtreme: await ODataStore.update

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme

I was running an Angular SPA with DevExtreme's DataGrid from Visual Studio in Chrome.

I have a method liks this:

```
    async remove(currentId: number): Promise<any> {
        const errorList = new Array<string>();

        const store = new ODataStore({
            // ...
        });

        try {
            store.update(currentId, { Deactivated: 'true' });
        } catch (error) {
            errorList.push(error.message);
        }

        return errorList;
    }
```

Now, the method returned too early, so I put an await here:

`await store.update(currentId, { Deactivated: 'true' });`

After saving, Chrome refreshed and the code worked, I got my error returned.

Next, I stopped execution in Visual Studio. When I tried to run it again, it failed. Using `ng serve`, I got the following error message:

`error TS1320: Type of 'await' operand must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member.`

According to the [DevExtreme Documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/ODataStore/Methods/#updatekey_values) I should get a native Promise -- plus, it actually did work at first. I'm puzzled. What's going on? How do I get it to compile?

Comment: If you use jQuery you get a jQuery Promise returned, which uses .done method instead of .then method.

Comment: How do I know what gets returned? And why did it work in hot edit?

Comment: Do you load jQuery in your application?

Comment: No. Using .then compiles and runs but I'd prefer using await.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this now:

```
        await store.update(currentId, { Deactivated: 'true' }).then(
            () => { },
            (error) => {
                errorList.push(error.message);
            }
        );
```

At least that solves the problem.

I still don't understand why my original approach didn't work (but did in hot edit). Answers to that are still appreciated.